# Trouble with JQuery Hoverintent slideUp

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-effects, hoverintent

I've been working on using the JQuery Hoverintent plugin and I've made some good progress, but I also have an issue using .hide, .slideUp, etc with the out: function to make sure that the overlay that hoverintent rolls in doesn't just immediately dissapear on hover out. Currently I have not been able to figure out why out: just makes the overlay immediately dissappear without any effect.

JQuery:

```
$(function satisfactionGaugeHoverIntent() {
    satisfactionConfig = {
        sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
        interval: 200, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
        timeout: 0, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
        over: function () {
            $('#satisfactionOverlay').show("drop", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
        },
        // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
        out: function () {
            $('#satisfactionOverlay').slideup('slow', 500);
        } // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
    }
    $('#satisfactionChartButton').hoverIntent(satisfactionConfig);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="satisfactionChartButton" class="large-3 large-offset-1 columns modalGaugeArea allGaugesSetup">
    <div class="chartModalTitle">Customer Satisfaction</div>
    <div id="customerSatisfactionGauge" class="gaugeContainer"></div>
    <input id="customerSatisfactionGaugeValue" type="hidden" data-url="@Url.Action(MVC.ATSNavigator.SatisfactionTotalAverageData())" />
    <div class="chartModalDialog">rating out of 5</div>
    <div id="satisfactionOverlay">
        <div class="overlayChartTitle">
            Customer Satisfaction<br />
            Chart
        </div>
        <img class="overlayImages" src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.img.wht_Desktop_Analytics_png)" />
        <div class="overlayChartDialog">Click to View Chart</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The over: function works well, out is the issue. Any suggestions why it seems like this function is not working?